# Integration JavaFx & LWJGL project

Tags: javafx, lwjgl

**I have a "LWJGL Project" ** and I want to make some buttons by JavaFx scene in this project or put LWJGL in JavaFx scene .. but I can't understand how to do that.. any one have idea ?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at https://github.com/AlmasB/FXGL which is an open source framework to do exactly what you want for 2D type GL renders mixed with JavaFX.

JMonkeyEngine has been adding features and examples that have JavaFX 2D HUDs and GUIs over their 3D displays, so you may want to look at those.

Otherwise if you need to write it yourself, a quick way is to use SwingNode: place the LWJGL component in a SwingNode and then the SwingNode into the JavaFX layout.  Be advised that you will have two separate rendering systems (JavaFX and Swing->OpenGL). Its really not hard but you'll need to code up any communications or event handlers that must "cross the divide".